# Proper divisors of 1?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, definition, divisibility

What are the proper divisors of 1?
I understand proper divisors do not include the number itself, but is 1 an exception or does it have no proper divisors?

Comment: If you restrict to $\mathbb{N}$ then Johanna is right, but if you allow integers then $-1$ is a proper divisor of $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the structure and/or your definition of proper divisor.

- If you say that a divisor $d$ of $b$ is proper if  $d \neq b$, then the proper divisors of $1$ are exactly the invertible elements/units of the ambient structure except $1$. That is none for $\mathbb{N}$, $-1$ for $\mathbb{Z}$, $-1,i,i$ for $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and so on.
- If you say that a divisor $d$ of $b$ is proper if $dc=b$ with a non-invertible $c$, that is  $d$ is not associated to $b$, then $1$ has no proper divisors.

Personally, I would go for the second definition.

Answer (score 1):

$1$ is a special case for almost everything. In this case, because it is the only natural number with no proper divisors, just as your definition implies. General rule with number theory: $1$ is always weird.

Comment: 2 is also weird.

Comment: Now the question is, if $a,b$ are weird, is $a+b$ weird?

Comment: @oxeimon  2 is odd not weird. :)

Comment: $2$ is odd, not really though